# Is there a way to ignore encoding type in Maven for Maven compiler plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-3, maven-compiler-plugin

I have a few developers working on `Windows` based `eclipse` and they use `CP1252` as encoding to develop `Java` projects. Some developers are working on `Mac/Linux` and they use `UTF-8`. So when I build my project using `maven compiler plugin` I always get the following error message

```
unmappable character for encoding windows-1252
```

I have the following properties in my `pom.xml`

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>cp1252</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

How do I completely ask `maven` to ignore the `encoding` ? Or what would be an ideal solution for this problem?

Comment: You should define a single encoding for the whole project. And the devs on Windows should simply change their encoding in IDE to UTF-8 etc. You can't ignore encoding, cause characters are encoded in one encoding which will result in failures...apart from that the java compiler will use the encoding (if no is defined) which is provided by the environment where you run...

Comment: Working under windows isn't excuse for not using utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

Never use anything lese, but UTF-8. It works cross-platform. Do as advied by khmarbaise and everything will do. Initially convert all broken files with `iconv` and you are done.